# Decode base64URL to base64 -- Swift

Tags: ios, swift, base64

I haven't found properly way how to decode base64URL to base64 format in swift.

According to [base64url to base64](http://kjur.github.io/jsjws/tool_b64udec.html) `hJQWHABDBjoPHorYF5xghQ`(base64URL) should be `hJQWHABDBjoPHorYF5xghQ==`(base64). Here could be more differences.

There are no solutions on stackoverflow.

Comment: Under the "Related" section to the right, there is a link about Base64URL decoding via JavaScript. A quick look at that would have given you a description of the difference.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

"base64url" differs from the standard Base64 encoding in two aspects:

- different characters are used for index 62 and 63 (`-` and `_` instead
  of `+` and `/`)
- no mandatory padding with `=` characters to make the string length
  a multiple of four.

(compare https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table).

Here is a possible conversion function:

```
func base64urlToBase64(base64url: String) -> String {
    var base64 = base64url
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "+")
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "_", with: "/")
    if base64.characters.count % 4 != 0 {
        base64.append(String(repeating: "=", count: 4 - base64.characters.count % 4))
    }
    return base64
}
```

Example:

```
let base64url = "hJQWHABDBjoPHorYF5xghQ"
let base64 = base64urlToBase64(base64url: base64url)
print(base64) // hJQWHABDBjoPHorYF5xghQ==

if let data = Data(base64Encoded: base64) {
    print(data as NSData) // <8494161c 0043063a 0f1e8ad8 179c6085>
}
```

For the sake of completeness, this would be the opposite conversion:

```
func base64ToBase64url(base64: String) -> String {
    let base64url = base64
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "+", with: "-")
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "/", with: "_")
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "=", with: "")
    return base64url
}
```

---

**Update for Swift 4:**

```
func base64urlToBase64(base64url: String) -> String {
    var base64 = base64url
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "+")
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "_", with: "/")
    if base64.count % 4 != 0 {
        base64.append(String(repeating: "=", count: 4 - base64.count % 4))
    }
    return base64
}
```

Comment: Mandrill custom tracking domain , track parameter p is also can be decoded this way. Heads up for the ones like me :)

Comment: I'm here for iOS-based Passkeys (that work on web perfectly!) 

Answer (score 9):

Here is a cleaned up version of what Martin posted within a Swift 4 extension:

```
import Foundation

/// Extension for making base64 representations of `Data` safe for
/// transmitting via URL query parameters
extension Data {

    /// Instantiates data by decoding a base64url string into base64
    ///
    /// - Parameter string: A base64url encoded string
    init?(base64URLEncoded string: String) {
        self.init(base64Encoded: string.toggleBase64URLSafe(on: false))
    }

    /// Encodes the string into a base64url safe representation
    ///
    /// - Returns: A string that is base64 encoded but made safe for passing
    ///            in as a query parameter into a URL string
    func base64URLEncodedString() -> String {
        return self.base64EncodedString().toggleBase64URLSafe(on: true)
    }

}

extension String {

    /// Encodes or decodes into a base64url safe representation
    ///
    /// - Parameter on: Whether or not the string should be made safe for URL strings
    /// - Returns: if `on`, then a base64url string; if `off` then a base64 string
    func toggleBase64URLSafe(on: Bool) -> String {
        if on {
            // Make base64 string safe for passing into URL query params
            let base64url = self.replacingOccurrences(of: "/", with: "_")
                .replacingOccurrences(of: "+", with: "-")
                .replacingOccurrences(of: "=", with: "")
            return base64url
        } else {
            // Return to base64 encoding
            var base64 = self.replacingOccurrences(of: "_", with: "/")
                .replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "+")
            // Add any necessary padding with `=`
            if base64.count % 4 != 0 {
                base64.append(String(repeating: "=", count: 4 - base64.count % 4))
            }
            return base64
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Handy for interacting with the GMail API from Swift.

Comment: `toggleBase64URLSafe` a really bizarre API, especially the name. Why not just split it into two separate functions?

Answer (score 0):

**This is objective c version of Base64URL to Base64**

-(NSString *) base64urlToBase64 :(NSString *)base64url
{

```
 NSString * base64 = [base64url stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@"+"];
base64 =  [base64 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_" withString:@"/"];
if(base64.length  % 4 != 0)
{
    base64 = [base64 stringByAppendingString:[self stringWithRepeatString:"=" times:(4 - base64.length % 4)]];
}
return  base64;
```

}

-(NSString*)stringWithRepeatString:(char*)characters times:(unsigned int)repetitions;
{

```
unsigned long stringLength = strlen(characters);
unsigned long repeatStringLength = stringLength * repetitions + 1;
char repeatString[repeatStringLength];

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < repetitions; i++) {
    unsigned int pointerPosition = i * repetitions;
    memcpy(repeatString + pointerPosition, characters, stringLength);
}

repeatString[repeatStringLength - 1] = 0;
return  [NSString stringWithCString:repeatString encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

}