# May not Decode .utf8 be working well in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, utf-8, encode

This is my string extension

```
extension String {

    func base64Encoded() -> String? {
        return data(using: .utf8)?.base64EncodedString()
    }

    func base64Decoded() -> String? {
        guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: self) else { return nil }
        return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    } 
}
```

and I try to decode the string which is

`eyJhdWQiOiIxMjM0IiwiaWF0IjoxNTMwNTM3MzQxLCJleHAiOjE1MzA1NDA5NDEsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6Ly82O1282Dcu2jgzL2E32ko2N2ciLCJzdWIiOiIwMUNGVjZaRjA3WkhKQ1FZQVRURDFOVkM0UCIsInJscyI6WyJjb2FjaC5kcml2ZXIiXX0`

to

```
{
  "aud": "1234",
  "iat": 1530537341,
  "exp": 1530540941,
  "iss": "http://6;]��7.�83/a7�J67g",
  "sub": "01CFV6ZF07ZHJCQYATTD1NVC4P",
  "rls": [
    "coach.driver"
  ]
}
```

however I haven't achieved it yet. The most strange thing about this subject, on online encode-decode converter websites, it is converted true. But in swift, I cannot do this.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43499651/decode-base64url-to-base64-swift.

Comment: thanks Martin, to be honest I realized that I should focus on different subject about this issue. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you Should use URl Safe encoding and decoding

```
extension String {
  //: ### Base64 encoding a string
  func base64Encoded() -> String? {
    if let data = self.data(using: .utf8) {
      return data.base64URLEncodedString()
    }
    return nil
  }

  //: ### Base64 decoding a string
  func base64Decoded() -> String? {


    if let data = Data(base64URLEncoded: self) {
      return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    }



    return nil
  }
}
extension Data {

  init?(base64URLEncoded string: String) {
    let base64Encoded = string
      .replacingOccurrences(of: "_", with: "/")
      .replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "+")
    // iOS can't handle base64 encoding without padding. Add manually
    let padLength = (4 - (base64Encoded.count % 4)) % 4
    let base64EncodedWithPadding = base64Encoded + String(repeating: "=", count: padLength)
    self.init(base64Encoded: base64EncodedWithPadding)
  }

  func base64URLEncodedString() -> String {
    // use URL safe encoding and remove padding
    return self.base64EncodedString()
      .replacingOccurrences(of: "/", with: "_")
      .replacingOccurrences(of: "+", with: "-")
      .replacingOccurrences(of: "=", with: "")
  }
}
```

Comment: it is really good trick about base64 encoding and decoding. Thanks a lot

Comment: Your code looks like a verbatim copy from https://github.com/auth0/Guardian.swift/blob/master/Guardian/Data%2BBase64URL.swift, without attribution.