# JWT verify signature using HMACSHA256 and show "Invalid Signature" by Swift

Tags: ios, swift, jwt, sha256, hmac

I have a question about JWT. 
I try to create own signature and use hard-code secret key "hello1234567890987654321test1234". 
And I use my function to create a signature and post to https://jwt.io/ to decode.
Then this webside show me "Invalid Signature".
What's wrong about me HMACSHA256 function? 
And I found the "-","_" in webside and convert "+","/" in my output signature. 
How to fix my output signature? 
Is this signature is correct?

I also find two HMACSHA256 methods searching in Google. I don't know which is better one. 
please give me some advice about choosing this.
Thanks.

Image:
[image: Question Image.]

Method1:

```
enum CryptoAlgorithm {
    case MD5, SHA1, SHA224, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512
    var HMACAlgorithm: CCHmacAlgorithm {
        var result: Int = 0
        switch self {
        case .MD5:      result = kCCHmacAlgMD5
        case .SHA1:     result = kCCHmacAlgSHA1
        case .SHA224:   result = kCCHmacAlgSHA224
        case .SHA256:   result = kCCHmacAlgSHA256
        case .SHA384:   result = kCCHmacAlgSHA384
        case .SHA512:   result = kCCHmacAlgSHA512
        }
        return CCHmacAlgorithm(result)
    }
    var digestLength: Int {
        var result: Int32 = 0
        switch self {
        case .MD5:      result = CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA1:     result = CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA224:   result = CC_SHA224_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA256:   result = CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA384:   result = CC_SHA384_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA512:   result = CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH
        }
        return Int(result)
    }
}

extension String {
    func hmac1(algorithm: CryptoAlgorithm, key: String) -> String {
        var result: [CUnsignedChar]
        if let ckey = key.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8), let cdata = self.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
            result = Array(repeating: 0, count: Int(algorithm.digestLength))
            CCHmac(algorithm.HMACAlgorithm, ckey, ckey.count-1, cdata, cdata.count-1, &result)
        } else {
            fatalError("Nil returned when processing input strings as UTF8")
        }

        return Data(bytes: result, count: result.count).base64EncodedString()
    }
}
```

Method2:

```
enum HMACAlgorithm {
    case MD5, SHA1, SHA224, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512

    func toCCHmacAlgorithm() -> CCHmacAlgorithm {
        var result: Int = 0
        switch self {
        case .MD5:
            result = kCCHmacAlgMD5
        case .SHA1:
            result = kCCHmacAlgSHA1
        case .SHA224:
            result = kCCHmacAlgSHA224
        case .SHA256:
            result = kCCHmacAlgSHA256
        case .SHA384:
            result = kCCHmacAlgSHA384
        case .SHA512:
            result = kCCHmacAlgSHA512
        }
        return CCHmacAlgorithm(result)
    }

    func digestLength() -> Int {
        var result: CInt = 0
        switch self {
        case .MD5:
            result = CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA1:
            result = CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA224:
            result = CC_SHA224_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA256:
            result = CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA384:
            result = CC_SHA384_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA512:
            result = CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH
        }
        return Int(result)
    }
}

extension String {
    func hmac2(algorithm: HMACAlgorithm, key: String) -> String {
        let cKey = key.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let cData = self.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        var result = [CUnsignedChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(algorithm.digestLength()))
        CCHmac(algorithm.toCCHmacAlgorithm(), cKey!, strlen(cKey!), cData!, strlen(cData!), &result)
        let hmacData:NSData = NSData(bytes: result, length: (Int(algorithm.digestLength())))
        let hmacBase64 = hmacData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength76Characters)
        return String(hmacBase64)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let headerString: String = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9"
        let payloadString: String = "eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ"
        let totalString: String = headerString + "." + payloadString

        let signature1 = totalString.hmac1(algorithm: .SHA256, key: "hello1234567890987654321test1234")
        let signature2 = totalString.hmac2(algorithm: .SHA256, key: "hello1234567890987654321test1234")

        print("signature1 : \(signature1)") // signature1 : L9YSDasvO2B5i8FZUczC+MAtSsTuM0Dj+FEpfn6uoRs=
        print("signature2 : \(signature2)") // signature2 : L9YSDasvO2B5i8FZUczC+MAtSsTuM0Dj+FEpfn6uoRs=

    }
}
```

Comment: Note: I answer your main problem below, but not the question about which method is better. Pls ask only one question at a time. Which one is better is also an opinion based question which is considered off-topic on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the encoding.
[JWT uses base64url encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-3) :

> A JWT is represented as a sequence of URL-safe parts separated by
> period ('.') characters.  Each part contains a base64url-encoded
> value.

but you are using base64 encoding in the signature, as shown in your code example.

The difference between [base64url encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#page-7) and base64 encoding is, that the characters '+' and '/' from the normal base64 output will be replaced by '-' and '_' and the trailing '=' (padding) will be omitted.

You say:

> And I found the "-","_" in webside and convert "+","/" in my output signature.

With '-' and '_' instead of '+' and '/' you have a correct output.

When you have a base64url encoded signature like this

> eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.L9YSDasvO2B5i8FZUczC-MAtSsTuM0Dj-FEpfn6uoRs

the signature wil be verified.

Comment: Thanks. Should I need to encode base64url from base64?  
Like following question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43499651/decode-base64url-to-base64-swift

Comment: yes, that's the point, the signature has to be base64url encoded. I'm not a swift user, so I'm not sure which methods you can use, but the result should be base64url encoded.

Comment: didn't notice the link in your first comment before. Yes, the  `base64ToBase64url` function in the accepted answer should be ok if the is no direct base64url conversion.