# receive space instead of + symbol in api from Swift IOS

Tags: ios, swift

I am passing Base64 encoded String to API call, but when we receive in API it shows as space .

> Eg.) Passing like this "kv+lluLOKRkGK6v+BqNPAPsx" But in API response
> receive "kv lluLOKRkGK6v BqNPAPsx" like this.

Can anyone explain why swift not sending "+" symbol in API.
And Please tell how to solve this.

Comment: It sounds like your base64-encoded data is being decoded as if it were [x-www-form-urlencoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#The_application/x-www-form-urlencoded_type), which (among other things) decodes `+` to space. But you need to post some code and describe the API in more detail if you want more help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the proper [Base64 variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table) that does not have the `+` character for REST calls: RFC 4648 base64url.

If you can't change the encoding, simply [transcode the Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43500088/1971013) you receive.